# Adding next paragraph/picture in the same line (empty space) not from the new line

Tags: html

I am trying to make a page by only using html , as i am new to html what i tried is

```
<div id="container" style="width:400px">    
    <div id="header" style="background-color:#0000;">
        <h1 style="margin-bottom:0;">Box Office</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="content" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;height:200px;width:400px;float:left;">
        <p>   
            <a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1170358/?ref_=hm_cht_t1" target="_blank" >1.   The Hobbit: The Desolation of Smaug    $31.5M </a>
        </p>
        <p>
            <a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1229340/?ref_=hm_cht_t2" target="_blank" >2.   Anchorman 2: The Legend Continues      $26.8M </a> 
        </p>
        <p>
            <a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2294629/?ref_=hm_cht_t3" target="_blank" >3.   Frozen  $19.6M </a>
        </p>
        <p>
            <a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1800241/?ref_=hm_cht_t4" target="_blank" >4.   American Hustle $19.1M </a>
        </p>
        <p>
            <a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2140373/?ref_=hm_cht_t5" target="_blank" >5.   Saving Mr. Banks    $9.34M </a>
        </p>
    </div>
```

Which make something like this

[image]

Now i want to start my next phase in the same flow but i want to start from the empty space after this block like in tha landscape flow , What i need to do so that my next part will start after it , i don't want to use the new line for next thing i want to enter

Reuired output

[image]

Now i want that when i start my new block it should start from after the first block like it shuld start from where i write "Now i want this"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/FQF7g/) solve your problem?
Are you trying to float the 2 container divs side-by-side in landscape?

```
<div id="container" style="width:400px">
    <div id="header" style="background-color:#0000;">
         <h1 style="margin-bottom:0;">Box Office</h1>

    </div>
    <div id="content" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;height:200px;width:600px;float:left;">
        <div style='width: 50%;display:inline-block;float:left;'>
            <p> <a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1170358/?ref_=hm_cht_t1" target="_blank">1.   The Hobbit: The Desolation of Smaug    $31.5M </a>

            </p>
            <p> <a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1229340/?ref_=hm_cht_t2" target="_blank">2.   Anchorman 2: The Legend Continues      $26.8M </a> 
            </p>
            <p> <a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2294629/?ref_=hm_cht_t3" target="_blank">3.   Frozen  $19.6M </a>

            </p>
            <p> <a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1800241/?ref_=hm_cht_t4" target="_blank">4.   American Hustle $19.1M </a>

            </p>
            <p> <a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2140373/?ref_=hm_cht_t5" target="_blank">5.   Saving Mr. Banks    $9.34M </a>

            </p>
        </div>
        <div style='width: 50%;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;background:#ddd;height:100%; '>
            <h2>Now I want this</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes , it work fine , but the thing which i need is , i will give seprate heading like Box Office on next block on which i wrote i want this , and they should be on small gap